# Pandas modify column vlaue to new per defined requirement

Tags: python, pandas

below is part of my data, currently, there's a requirement to change the old_data to the required one. Just use the below data for example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'old_data':['12-13A:A','12-13A:B','12-13A:C','12-13A:G','39-40:A','39-40:B','39-40:G','13A-19:A','13A-19:B',
                               '13A-19:C','13A-19:D','13A-19:E','13A-19:F','13A-19:G']})
```

The pre-defined rule is that the digit range difference of each group's old data is 2(like 39-40),3(like 12-13A), or 6(like 13A-19). And if the single digit of a number is 4, then we need to change it to the number before that number appending an **'A'**. For example, the number **14**, we need to change it to **13A**, **23A** means **24**. If the old_data is **33-35:B**, the required data shall be **Bed 33A**.

Appreciate you can give some ideas for how to modify the old_data column to the required_data column with **Pandas**, Thanks.

[image: sample_data_pic]

Comment: transfer the old data to the required data with Pandas

Comment: yes, but the data in the question is just a part of the whole. I need to find a method to convert all the data from the old format to the new required format.

Comment: #1: can you explain for 13A-19:G, why required data is 13A-19? #2 What is the required data for 13A-26:G?

Comment: @RaymondKwok the max difference between the start and the end is 6, so no data like 13A-26. If the data contains ':G', the required data just need to remove the string':G'.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially your data is `range:alphabet_index`.

Some helper functions. I will switch between your 'no-four-in-the-last-digit' integer system and the normal integer system

```
import re

def to_number_system(s):
    return int(re.sub('3A$', '4', s))

def to_no_four_system(n):
    return 'Bed ' + re.sub('4$', '3A', str(n))
```

The following function `map` your alphabetical indices to the Bed numbers generated by the range, or `G` to the range itself.

```
def do_the_job(df):
    _range = df['_range'].iloc[0]
    range_start, range_end = map(to_number_system, _range.split('-'))
    numbers = map(to_no_four_system, range(range_start, range_end+1))

    return df['index'].map(dict(zip('ABCDEF', numbers), G=_range))

df[['_range', 'index']] = df['old_data'].str.split(':', expand=True)
df['required_data'] = df.groupby('_range').apply(do_the_job).droplevel(0)
```

Take care of the formatting

```
df.drop(columns=['_range', 'index'])
```